# Quick access to categorized elements in javascript array?

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following javasccript

```
var myobj = {
   name: "Julia",
   birthdate: "xxxx",
   movies: [{title: "movie1", rating: 5, genre: "Horror"}, {title: "movie2", rating 3, genre: "Comedy"},{title: "movie3", rating 3, genre: "Comedy"}, {title: "movie4", rating 3, genre: "Comedy"}, {title: "movie5", rating 3, genre: "Horror"}]
}
```

I am looking for the best way to retrieve all "Horror" movies (could be comedy) without having to loop through everything in an array. I know I could create a for loop to iterate through the movies array with an if condition, but that requires me to look through every single movie. If there was some way I could do:

```
horrorMovies = [//array containing all horror movies without iterating through everything to iterate through all moves to look at their genre attribute]
```

Or is it some good practice to have some additional field in myobj to be some kind of lookup table:

```
myobj.genreindexes = [];
```

and have that keep track of all the genres like: genreindexes['Horror'] = '//Array indexes where element is Horror'?

Or is there some easy way I could do: myobj.movies['-insert genrehere-'] and get the list of movies? Any advice and samples would be appreciated.

If there is no ideal solution, samples using any library would be okay too.

Comment: How could you do that unless you created an index while populating the array?

Comment: There is no way to do what you describe without iteration. JS objects are unsuited to this sort of deep look-up. Have you looked into WebSQL?

Comment: If objects are in an array like that, then *something* is going to have to iterate over the array to find your objects. That's the nature of that data structure and it cannot be avoided. JavaScript doesn't have operators for list comprehensions, and even if it did it's still the case that something in the runtime would be making a linear pass over your array.

Comment: Have you looked at underscore.js - http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: @techfoobar Wouldn't that just be library sugar over iteration (unless it does indexing while populating)?

Comment: Mentioned because it has some real time-saving helpers.. But yeah, it wont directly help in making the searching faster .. thats why I posted as comment instead of as answer ;-)

Comment: Perhaps JLinq? http://hugoware.net/Projects/jlinq but this is probably just syntactic sugar compared to a for loop.

Comment: @techfoobar Could you post an answer using underscore.js that could be applicable to what I am looking for?

Comment: Could anyone post an answer using underscore.js or JLinq that could be applicable?

Comment: Underscore.js is library sugar. It wouldn't get round the problem of needing to iterate - it's just it might have some handy methods of doing it. It would still be iteration, though.

Comment: @Seiverence Most JS libs have some form of collect/map--it's *not* the answer to your question, although it looks and feels nicer than looping. If you're just looking for sugar, consider editing your question to indicate as much. IMO this is better suited for server-side work, or indexing-while-building. Also, have you proven there is a real bottleneck here? If you're sending enough data to make looping "too slow", you likely have other more serious problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seiverence,

The only way to access a group of objects that share a characteristic without iterating over all of them is to put them all in a box as you insert them.  Of course, when I say box, I mean in a data structure that keeps them all together.

That said, here's some different scenarios to consider:

1. You write an iterator for a big bucket of items and tell the iterator to extract what you want.  In effect, you are iterating over all of the items, but it allows you to be "lazy" when querying for what you want.  This is probably not what you want.
2. You really want to keep them separated by some common property.  In this case, you make separate buckets for every common property (hash table).

I would recommend option 2 as it gives quick access to what you want.

Here's a link that explains how to use hash tables in Javascript:
http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned, storing the indices of titles based on genre is likely the best way that can guarantee performance improvement (or you could go for sorted storage and binary search etc, but i think that would be an overkill). One clean way would be to add a function named `pushMovie(_name, _genre, ...)` to the Array prototype and use that for populating your movies. Inside `pushMovie(..)` you can write code to populate the index as well..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think a possible good way to do what you need is using jLinq.

**Library:** https://raw.github.com/hugoware/jlinq-beta/master/jlinq.js

This is my code but I also made you a jsfiddle:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/anMDt/

```
//Your json obj array
var myobj = {
   name: "Julia",
   birthdate: "xxxx",
   movies: [{title: "movie1", rating: 5, genre: "Horror"}, {title: "movie2", rating: 3, genre: "Comedy"},{title: "movie3", rating: 3, genre: "Comedy"}, {title: "movie4", rating: 3, genre: "Comedy"}, {title: "movie5", rating: 3, genre: "Horror"}]
}

//Just horror movies in object
var horrorMovies = jlinq.from(myobj.movies).starts('genre', 'Horror').select();

// See the console with your horror movies
console.log(horrorMovies);
```

**Result:**

[image]

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do a linear pass once, and generate indices for all fields. Yes, it is not zero-cost; but then again, there's no such thing as a free lunch.

Generically speaking,

```
function index(array) {
    var fields = {}
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        var o = array[i]
        for (var f in o) {
            if ( ! o.hasOwnProperty(f)) {
               continue;
            } else if (fields[f] === undefined) {
                fields[f] = {};
                fields[f][o[f]] = [o];
            } else if (fields[f][o[f]] === undefined) {
                fields[f][o[f]] = [o];
            } else {
                fields[f][o[f]].push(o);
            }
        }
    }
    return fields;
}
```

This allows you to write

```
var db = index(myobj.movies); // takes O(C), where C = number of rows x cols 
db["genre"]["Comedy"];         // returns an array w/ movies 2, 3, 4 - in O(1)
db["genre"]["Horror"];         // returns an array w/ movies 1, 5
...
```

A classic space-for-time trade-off. Also, [see it working (JsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/8gNNf/)